# Dynamic session key in redis store depending on request domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app which has slightly diffrent behaviour when accessing diffrent subdomains. Let's say app has domain **test.com** and I two subdomains: **one** and **two**.

I need to use redis session and I'm storing cookie "redis_session" on whole host (so each domain will store diffrent session_id). But in redis I'd like to prefix the session key depending of the subdomain, for example

1. **one.test.com** uses cookie named **redis_session** which has value **123** but stored in redis as **one:123**
2. **two.test.com** used cookie named **redis_session** which has value **321** but stored in redis as **two:321**

I found out that I can specify the namespace for the redis session in config:

```
  config.session_store :redis_store, :key => 'redis_session', 
    :redis_server => { :namespace => "..." }
```

But I can only assign "static" namespace, I can't figure out how I can set namespace dynamically depending on current request to check the domain.

I've googled for solutions but no results so far, and didn't find any helpful gem which behaves similiar way.

Any help appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `redis-store` gem?  Check out this [pull request](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store/pull/163/files) for that gem - it looks like dynamic namespaces were added last month.

Comment: Thanks for that, however I've monkeypatched `redis-store` to allow lambdas before I've posted a question here, and the problem was that I couldn't get access to the request object, since I have to set this storage in config file, not in controller. I actually just tried to dynamically change the session storage in `before_filter`, using lambda and having request object, but it looks like rails always falls back to default session storage (which is cookie-based) and ignores any config-changes on fly